# Script to populate timeslot table with 1-hour timeslots

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've table in my schema => TimeSlot, which has several attributes with id, start time, end time.
So the question is: how can you make a script that will make 23/24 records, for which starttime - endtime, for example, 0.00-1.00, 1.00-2.00, etc.

i've tried this with some example, but can not figure out how to code it(not even know if it is correct):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
TRUNCATE TABLE TimeSlot

DECLARE @InitHour TIME(0) = '1'
DECLARE @FinitHour TIME(0) = '24'

WHILE @InitHour < @FinitHour
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TimeSlot(
        TimeSlotID, StartTime, EndTime
    )
    SELECT
```

Comment: SQL Server has [WHILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) loops.

Comment: @O.Jones OPs code has a WHILE loop. I suspect their issue is being able to create a value start and end time.

Comment: It does, but that doesn't mean you should use them, @O.Jones .

Comment: `24:00:00` is not valid for a time in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to generate a sequence of numbers, you can do this using any table that has the required number of rows and use `row_number` for an arbitrary number sequence.

```
with seq as (
    select top(24) Row_Number() over (order by (select null))-1 n
    from sys.syscomments
)
insert into TimeSlot (StartTime, EndTime)
select Convert(time,Concat(n,':00')) StartTime, 
       DateAdd(hour, 1, Convert(time,Concat(n,':00'))) EndTime
from seq
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question is that you need to generate the results somehow.  There are lots of methods.  If you have a table lying around with at least 24 rows, then you can use that.  A "native" SQL method uses a recursive CTE>

Then, the `TimeSlotID` should be generated automatically (typically as an identity column):

```
WITH CTE as (
      SELECT convert(datetime, '01:00:00') as StartTime
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, StartTime)
      FROM CTE
      WHERE StartTime < convert(datetime, '23:00:00')
     )
INSERT INTO TimeSlot (StartTime, EndTime)
    SELECT StartTime, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, StartTime)
    FROM CTE;
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9bac2/12

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle, but it did not work setting `@inithour` and `@FinitHour`. I'll humbly edit your answer (more clever than mine!) to make it work as-is.

Comment: Her's my table lying around that has 24 rows `(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))` happy now?

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4cb97/17

```
set nocount on

declare @hour int = 0

while @hour <= 23
begin
  declare @time datetime =
    convert(
      datetime,
      convert(varchar, @hour) + ':00:00'
    )

  insert into TimeSlot(StartTime, EndTime)
  values(
    @time, dateadd(hour, 1, @time)
  )
    
  set @hour = @hour + 1
end

select *
from TimeSlot
```